# Average difference between two dates, grouped by a third field?

Tags: sql

So say we have 3 fields, `username, start_date, end_date`

Users start and stop multiple records, eg below bob has started and stopped two records.

```
bob   1/2/13 11:00  1/2/13 13:00
jack  1/2/13 15:00  1/2/13 18:00
bob   2/2/13 14:00  1/2/13 19:00
```

I need to know the average time taken (ie diff between start and end), in hours, for each user (ie group by user, not just for each row).

I can't quite get my head around how to do the diff, average AND group by? Any help?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't specify the granularity you want for the diff. This does it in days:

```
select username, avg(end_date - start_date) as avg_days
from mytable
group by username
```

If you want the difference in seconds, use [`datediff()`](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff):

```
select username, avg(datediff(ss, start_date, end_date)) as avg_seconds
...
```

datediff can measure the diff in any time unit up to years by varying the first parameter, which can be ss, mi, hh, dd, wk, mm or yy.

Comment: Wow, ok, simpler than I imagined. Guess I was making it more complex in my head than it needed to be.

Comment: Which version of PostgreSQL you're using here? Do you mind creating a SQLFiddle for this snippet? @NickFoote, I doubt this will work on a recent enough version of PostgreSQL.

Comment: psql doesn't have `datediff()` function. @vyegorov, why did you remove `postgresql` tag from the question?

Comment: huh. I'm getting arithmetic overflow exceptions. (using the 'ss' option of `datediff`)

Comment: @TheHitchenator Dates more than 66.5 years apart have a difference in seconds greater than a signed 4 byte integer can hold. Big deal.

Comment: @Bohemian Surely not the cause... the system logging these dates has only been running for two years! but thanks for the tip - gives me some backing for what to look into!

Comment: @TheHitchenator how long it’s been running does not necessarily govern what data is in the database - stuff can sneak in. Try `select min(myDateColumn), max(myDateColumn) from myTable` and see how it looks.

Comment: @Bohemian As expected, the earliest date is from 2018 and latest date is from 2020... no outliers.
This is mostly why I'm perplexed by the overflow - I already kinda knew they wouldn't be there due to checks made for a BSI standard.

Comment: @TheHitchenator any null dates?

Comment: @Bohemian yes, but I was filtering those out in the WHERE clause... I'll try again, possible I missed a column in that. Thanks for the help brianstorming!

Comment: @TheHitchenator AFAIK non-index conditions in the where clause fire *after* result rows are created, so depending on the optimizer choice it’s possible a null date is involved with a calculation even though you are filtering them out of the final result.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT [username], AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, start_date, end_date))
FROM [table]
GROUP BY [username]
```

Comment: Thanks for this, great help real quick. Unfortunately I can't tick two answers.