# Average of differences between 2 numbers located in 2 different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timestamp

I have a SQL problem that, I think, go far beyond my current knowledge. I have two tables and in each 2 dates in timestamp. I would like to have the average time between those 2 dates, average involving all fields entered in the tables.

I hope I would be clearer doing a simplification of my SQL tables and what I want to do :


**-- Table 1 : study**
-- -- id
-- -- timestamp (date of input, start of the study for instance)

**-- Table 2 : study_monitoring**
-- -- id
-- -- id_study
-- -- timestamp_2 (start of the first stage, for instance)

I want to get the average time between *`timestamp`* and *`timestamp_2`*.
I have first to link the *`study_monitoring`* field to its proper *study* field thanks to the ID located in **table 2**.

Then to do the difference between the 2 timestamps (the second being always superior to the other). Repeating this for all the fields and finally get the average.
Doing it in several SQL requests wouldn't bother me, it would be in a simple PHP function that return the average of the difference of timestamp.
I don't really know where to start, does the modelling of my tables allow such computing ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You need to do a `join` of the two tables to get the pairing of the numbers per row so you can take the differences, then take an aggregate average. But what do you mean by *average time between `timestamp` and `timestamp_2`*? Do you just mean the difference between the time stamps in minutes or something else? That's a place to start. Go off and work some ideas and come back with a more specific question.

Comment: [take a look at post here may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895782/average-difference-between-two-dates-grouped-by-a-third-field)

Comment: Is timestamp a TIMESTAMP or DATE or DATETIME?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

```
select s.id,
       avg(to_seconds(sm.timestamp_2) - to_seconds(s.timestamp)) as avg_in_seconds
from study s left join
     study_monitoring sm
     on s.id = sm.id_study
group by s.id;
```

This assumes that seconds are a reasonable unit of time.  There are other ways to get other units or to convert this back to an interval representation.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the average time difference in seconds.

```
SELECT Avg(DATEDIFF(second, s.timestamp, sm.timestamp_2))[AverageDifferenceSeconds]
FROM study s inner join study_monitoring sm on s.id=sm.id_study
```

Comment: Your functions and syntax are for SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: Yes, I did miss that it was for MySQL, yours is a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `Study` ( `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `Start` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `Study_Monitoring` ( `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `Study_Id_FK` INT NOT NULL, `StartPhase` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `Study` (`Start`) 
VALUES (DATE("2016-05-25")),(DATE("2016-05-25")),(DATE("2016-05-25")),(DATE("2016-05-25")),(DATE("2016-05-25"));

INSERT INTO `Study_Monitoring` (`Study_Id_FK`, `StartPhase`) 
VALUES (0, NOW()), (1, NOW()),(2, NOW()),(3, NOW()),(4, NOW())
```

You would get the average diff in seconds (assuming this is MySQL)
with the following command:

```
SELECT  AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, Table_1.Start, Table_2.StartPhase))
FROM Study AS Table_1 
  INNER JOIN 
    Study_Monitoring AS Table_2 
      ON Table_1.Id = Table_2.Study_Id_FK
```

TIMESTAMPDIFF is described [here](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timestampdiff-function.php) to accept the units

`FRAC_SECOND (microseconds), SECOND, MINUTE, HOUR, DAY, WEEK, MONTH, QUARTER, or YEAR.`

Feel free to change it as appropriate. :)

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/532992/3/0)

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the granularity you want for the diff. This does it in days:

```
select username, avg(end_date - start_date) as avg_days
from mytable
group by username
```

If you want the difference in seconds, use datediff():

```
select username, avg(datediff(ss, start_date, end_date)) as avg_seconds
...
```

datediff can measure the diff in any time unit up to years by varying the first parameter, which can be ss, mi, hh, dd, wk, mm or yy.