# Calculating an average time value between 2 timestamps across an entire table of data

Tags: mysql, select, average

I have a table, that has a unix timestamp field for start and end of a process.

I have seen a number of suggestions that appear to calculate averages unsing Datediff, but as I am using unix timestamps, this isn't necessary, is it?

I can calculate the time difference for each entry (end-start) but how can I calculate an average of all of these differences across the entire data set?

I tried;

SELECT AVG(`endtime`-`starttime`) AS length FROM `survey` WHERE `complete` = '1'

But the value it returns is negative, and so I am thinking that I have got this all wrong.

Any advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Average difference between two dates, grouped by a third field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895782/average-difference-between-two-dates-grouped-by-a-third-field)

Comment: Is there always an `endtime`?

Comment: There is an endtime if the survey is complete (complete = '1')

Comment: I've read the article that John suggested, but I can't get my head around the difference in application between datetime and unix timestamps

Comment: The SQL looks right, so I think you probably have some rows with invalid or unexpected data.  Try:  `select * from survey where complete = '1' and (endtime < starttime or endtime is null or starttime is null)`

Comment: Thank you. I just hunted through the table, and found a single entry from a testing phase where there was no endtime. I now have a much more reasonable calculation. Thank juergen d and jnylen.